# Javascript remove item from array but keep the reference number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
var myArr= ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four"];
```

if I want to access any value in this array I would do something like...

```
var numberTwo = myArr[2]
```

My issue is that I want to delete one item from my array, but not loose the existing number reference... something like this...

```
myArr.splice(2,1)
```

So my array will now be...

```
["zero", "one", "three", "four"]
```

Is it possible to delete item 2 for example but still be able to access "three" using this code : `var numberThree = myArr[3]` instead of `var numberThree = myArr[2]`

Comment: Set `myArr[2]` to null?

Comment: what is the benefit?

Comment: Why do you want to delete it..?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Why do you need to delete an item from an array but not reindex the array? This seems like a XY problem and if you described the larger issue you are trying to solve, the solution is probably something other than using an array. Maybe what you need is an object? `{ 0: "zero", 1:"one",... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely not. If you remove something from the array, array items are re-indexed to properly feet from `0` to `length - 1`. Actually it not removes anything, but creates a new array and omit the selected items range.

But if you have some logic with it and it is mandatory, you can set it's value to `undefined` or `null` and in your code check the value. If it is `undefined` or `null`, consider it is removed from the array.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) for deleting an item of an array.

For checking, you could use [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), because the value of deleted items of the array is `undefined`, which is not different from a intended value of `undefined`. To check a sparse item, you could take the `in` operator.

```js
var array = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four"];

delete array[3];

console.log(array[3]);   // undefined
console.log(array[4]);   // 'four'
console.log(3 in array); // false
console.log(1 in array); // true
```

Comment: You *could*, but you really probably *shouldn't*

Comment: @MattBurland, the task is to keep the index. with splicing, the index moves.

Comment: No doubt. But you are definitely abusing an array. This isn't what an array is for.

Comment: @MattBurland, abusing is a hash word, i would try to work without, but i do not condemn it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a hash table instead:

```
var myArr = {0: "zero", 1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three", 4: "four"};
```

Then you could delete any element you want:

```
delete myArr[2];
```

And then access the elements in the same way:

```
myArr[3] //=> three
myArr //=> {0: "zero", 1: "one", 3: "three", 4: "four"}
```

You can use a more readable keys:

```
var myArr = { "elem0": "zero", "elem1": "one" }
```

Comment: Don't change the shape of the object during the execution. It causes the engines not to optimize the code

Comment: This is true only for V8, and it happens when we extend the object and not when we delete a property. What will have an impact on optimization is to delete an array element and not a hash-table entry.

Comment: When you delete, new class is generated for the object and it differs from which the V8 expects to work with.